# Probability that a randomly chosen centorid will be chosen from a cluster

Tags: combinatorics, machine-learning, data-mining

k-means is a data mining algorithm useful for clustering purposes:

Given K equally sized clusters, the probability that a randomly chosen initial
centroid will come from any given cluster is 1/K, but the probability that each
cluster will have exactly one initial centroid is much lower. (It should be clear
that having one initial centroid in each cluster is a good starting situation for K-
means.) **In general, if there are K clusters and each cluster has n points, then the
probability, p, of selecting in a sample of size K one initial centroid from each
cluster is given by**:

number of ways to select one centroid from each cluster$/$number of ways to select K centroids is equal to $ K!n^{ K}$ $/$ $(Kn)^{K}$

But i do not get how can we arrive at that formula?

Shouldn't it be the combination of k different items from the k different clusters?